# Pandas DataFrame - how to merge groupby calculations back into DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by, dataframe

I am new to DataFrames. After a groupby aggregate calculation, it produces a DataFrame/data series with only the groupby keys and calculated value.

for a dataframe: -

```
df=pd.dataframe.merge(left,right,left_on=['key1','key2'],right_on=['key1','key2']).groupby(['colA','colB'])['colC'].sum()
```

df would generate a dataframe of A, B, sum(C). I want to have a resultset that has column left.D as well but its not part of a key or computation, how do it do that?

Comment: In pandas you have similar tools. see `pd.merge`, `pd.groupby`. You just have to break the sql statement down to `selection` and `join` and `grouping` steps and do them manually one after another.

Comment: yes, i did a pd.merge and groupby, but the output is a dataframe of groupby keys and the computed value only. but if you look at my sql statement, i have a value tableA.B column that i need to be in the result, i cant find a way to include it. tableA.B column is correlated to tableA.A, but cannot be used in join because tableB doesnt have that value

Comment: I really don't understand your problem. You have the `groupby` key. So you can use it in an inner join to get the rest of the attributes.

Comment: could you add example dataframes into your question?

Comment: I work around it by merging df result back into 'left', it worked but i am not too sure its the most efficient way to do it.